# How many times will merge and mergesort be run in mergesort algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

These are homework questions, but I would like to understand the concepts behind them, not just get the answers.

I know that the running time of MergeSort is O(nlogn). It seems that the merge method would have to run n times (because it has to merge all of the arrays, and there ends up being n arrays). Therefore, I thought I could deduce that the MergeSort() method would be called logn times. I also thought that made sense because it is dividing the array, so it would keep dividing itself by 2, so logn.

Therefore, I feel that the answers are C and A, respectively. But I am a bit skeptical because of the note saying the questions are asking how many times the method is called, not the running time. I would appreciate some advice and an explanation of counting vs running time. Thank you.

The questions are as follows:

18.
We defined a recursive method MergeSort() to divide the input array in the middle and recursively sort each part.

Suppose we have an array of length n, and we apply this merge sort algorithm. How many times will the MergeSort() method be called?

A. O(n)
B. O(n2)
C. O( log(n) )
D. O( n log(n) )

[[[
Note that this and the next question ask to count how many times the methods are called. This is NOT about the running time; it is about the counting.
]]]

19.
Suppose we have an array of length n, and we apply this merge sort algorithm. How many times will the merge() method be called?

A. O(n)
B. O(n2)
C. O( log(n) )
D. O( n log(n) )

Source code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort
{
public static void merge(int[] data, int first, int last)
{
    int[] temp = new int[last - first + 1]; // A new array to hold the merged result
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    int i = first, j = mid + 1, k = 0;

    // Copy smaller item from each subarray into temp until one
    // of the subarrays is exhausted
    while (i <= mid && j <= last)
    {
        if (data[i] < data[j])
            temp[k++] = data[i++];
        else
            temp[k++] = data[j++];
    }

    // Copy remaining elements from first subarray, if any
    while (i <= mid)
        temp[k++] = data[i++];

    // Copy remaining elements from second subarray, if any
    while (j <= last)
        temp[k++] = data[j++];

    // Copy merged data back into original array
    for (i = first; i <= last; i++)
        data[i] = temp[i - first];
}

public static void merge2(int[] data, int first, int last)
{
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    int i = first, j = mid + 1;
    int len = last - first + 1;
    int[] temp = new int[len];

    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
        if (i == mid + 1)               // The left part is done
            temp[k] = data[j++];
        else if (j == last + 1)         // The right part is done
            temp[k] = data[i++];
        else if (data[i] < data[j])     // Get one from the left
            temp[k] = data[i++];
        else                            // Get one from the right
            temp[k] = data[j++];
    }

    // Copy merged part back into the original array
    for (i = first; i <= last; i++)
        data[i] = temp[i - first];
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] data, int first, int last)
{
    // intermediate result
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, first, last + 1)));

    if (first >= last)
        return;

    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    mergeSort(data, first, mid);
    System.out.println("testingMerge");
    mergeSort(data, mid + 1, last);
    System.out.println("testingMerge");

    // merge two sorted parts
    merge(data, first, last);   //merge2(data, first, last);

    // intermediate result

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    System.out.println("begin with: \n" + Arrays.toString(array));
    System.out.println("------------------");

    mergeSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);

    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("end with: \n" + Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer appears to be correct.

> We defined a recursive method MergeSort() to divide the input array in the middle and recursively sort each part.

So we expect to call `MergeSort` `log n` times. Since each recursive step is one half the length of `n`.

Since we know that merge sort is O(n log n) could stop here as `MergeSort` is called `log n` times, the `merge` must be called `n` times. But we can also reason that we must subdivide the `n` items until each input consists of one element. Clearly we must merge `n` such one item lists to arrive at a final out consisting of `n` items.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea why the prof would have made a note about the distinction between the # of times it was called and the running time? It seems like the running time of the merge method should be O(n), which is equivalent to the # of times it is called? Isn't a running time just the # of times something is called proportionate to the size n? So wouldn't they be equivalent?

Comment: @user120920 No. Running time is an actual observed result on non-deterministic hardware and multi-user multi-threaded multi-core modern machines you might expect that it's proportional to number of times called. But data locality, and keeping a cpu pipeline full, can lead to unexpectedly large benefits in other algorithms. Some sort implementations switch to insertion sort when the number of items to be added is small (like 7). See [this wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Comparison_with_other_sort_algorithms) for example.

Comment: I believe merge is actually called n-1 times.